# Java split before and stop

Tags: java

I have a JTextField and I'm using it to put info into a JTextArea. I want a command that puts text into it, but I'm having to use split to check if it's the /text command.  When I do "/text Message To Put", it cuts off at the spaces.  How can I get the "Message to put" as a whole to output to the JTextArea?

Comment: It would be clearer and better if you posted the code you're talking about.  Not the whole program, mind you, just the parts where you manipulate the message and add it to the JTextArea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to the following to parse the text that is in the `JTextField`.

```
String messageToPut = jTextField.GetText();
if (messageToPut.startsWith("/text ")) {
    messageToPut = 
       messageToPut.substring("/text ".length()).trim();
}
```

The above just looks to see if the text starts with `/text` and, if if does, it trims the `/text` off of the beginning and leaves you with only the message.

Comment: I think I'd use the single-parameter substring() call here.

Comment: You probably want to check whether it starts with "/text " (including the space at the end.) That way it won't flag as true if it starts with /textcommand2 or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing something like splitting the string by a space, grabbing the first element in the returned array, checking whether it's /text, and if it is taking element 1 as the message (thus ignoring any later items in the array.) You could concatenate these later items and then use this concatenated value as the one to put into your text area.

A better alternative though might be to use the startsWith() method to check if the first bit of the text is "/text", then the substring() method to remove the /text bit before adding the message to the text area.